# Spring Config for the Ignite

Tags: spring, ignite

I have a block of the spring Configuration of Ignite. The current scenario as below:

We want to deploy the Ignite Cache in the Different Stand-alone Servers. And modify the existing code to access the Ignite Cache Server, then using the spring @Cacheable Annotation to implement the cache. My configuration as blow:

```
<bean id="igniteCacheManager" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager">
     <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="myGrid"/>
     <property name="configuration">
        <bean id="gridCfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>(server Ip Address)</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

But it doesn't work, and the Spring application can't startup now.

it shows the error message

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class" [50000-192]

could you help to do me a favor, whether our solution is feasible? and how to config the spring to access the stand-alone ignite server?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide full stack trace for exception. Likely explanation is JAR hell and as is unrelated to Spring or Ignite.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included h2 dependency ? If not , try to add this dependency in your pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.196</version>
 </dependency>
```